# NoMethodError in Rails::Conductor::ActionMailbox::InboundEmailsController#create + RubyonRails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-6, inbound

Any idea why I'm getting this errors on my localhost when I send an inbound email?

It is not a part of code that I can fix. Maybe some settings?

http://localhost:3000/rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails

[image]

Comment: What file is this? What is the full backtrace? What is `self.class`? It's very hard to debug an error based on a screenshot of the error message, with key context missing.

Comment: Are you implying that this used to work on rails 5?

Comment: The error says that `self.class.service` evaluates to `nil` and that the `name` method is unavailable for a `nil` value.

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced this in an application that didn't use active_storage before adding in action_mailbox (which depends on active_storage).

The solution that worked for us was to specify an active_storage config like:

**config/storage.yml**

```yaml
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage" %>
```

And reference which active storage config to load the environment:

**config/environments/development.rb**

```rb
Rails.application.configure do
  # ... other stuff
  config.active_storage.service = :local
end
```